# A complex UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout similar to an Instagram Explore Page

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, ios13, uicollectionviewlayout

I want within `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout` to make the following Layout:

- three sections with horizontal collection
- inside a cell of the third section lies a vertical collection
- when you click on any cell in the 2nd section, the third section should scroll to the same index
- when scrolling the third section, the 2nd section should be selected accordingly and scrolled if necessary

I'll give you my sketch(I'm not Picasso):

[image]

My solution looks like this:

- сreating three orthogonal sections
- the heights of the first two are static
- the height of the third section are dynamic, is the entire height of the collection, or less
- inside each cell of the third section there will be a controller with a collection, instead of just a collection. I think it will be easier to work with data in MVC manner

But there are unresolved problems:

- I do not have direct access to the internal scroll sections. I can't scroll them programmatically from here

**Are my thoughts correct or can I do something better and easier?**
[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: No need for `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout` just use a collection view at the top and a `PageViewController` at the bottom.

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini This solution is not suitable